# How to remove delay on useMutation?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a button and I want to using the `loading` prop from the `useMutation` hook to activate the spinner, but there is the slightest lag after i click the button due to the delay in response. The loading prop is not immediately set to true.

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
const [addTodo, { data }] = useMutation(ADD_TODO);

return (
...

<Button onClick={() => addTodo("test")} loading={loading}>Submit</Button>
// Will take 500ms or so until the spinner spins due to delay in receiving 
// which defeats the purpose of the loading spinner

</form> 
)}
```

Is there an elegant solution for ensuring `loading` is set to true the instant I fire the mutation?

Comment: I always use `loading` outside of my main component to display instead a 'Loading' component. Not familiar with your usage, so sending a comment not an answer. I imagine you can use a piece of state to keep track of the moment of button press via an `onClick` handler to immediately disable the button but then re-enable it when `loading` is false again.

Comment: Have you checked if the Button component is not having issues with something stalling the rendering of the spinner? The `loading` property of the mutation result is always set to true immediately mutation function is called. In your example above you are not extracting the loading property though. Are you using the `loading` property of the *query* perhaps?

Comment: @hbentlov that was a typo, I meant to extract it